# Is it possible to get all lists associated with a list email using the Pardot API?

Tags: email, api, list, pardot

I would like to find the lists associated with a list email using the Pardot API.  The [list query](http://developer.pardot.com/kb/api-version-3/lists/) doesn't seem to support parameter values that would allow for this type of query.  Is there any way to make this association?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, unfortunately there isn't a way to directly query the data you are looking for.

You MIGHT be able to put this together yourself by using various APIs to extract Prospects, VisitorActivity, Lists, List Memberships....then looking at the VisitorActivity for the Email and joining together all the information.  Not a pretty solution, but depending on your use case (and likely volume of data) this just might work.